# Keycloak password policy

Tags: php, symfony, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

So, I have integrated keycloak API endpoints in my Symfony project..

Regarding https://ultimatesecurity.pro/post/password-policy/ we have added 'not username' policy to test on creating new user within the app.

Idea is to delcare specific method with defined endpoint which will do this.

I was checking the documentation and could not find any endpoint that can check for password policy rules --> [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_passwordpolicytyperepresentation)

Idea for it:

```
$options = [
        'headers' => $this->getAuthJsonHeaders()
    ];

    try {
        $endpoint = sprintf('auth/admin/realms/%s/', $this->realm);
        $response = $this->request('GET', $endpoint, $options);
        return $response;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->exception('Can`t reset user password on Keycloak. ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

This is what I get:

[image]

when dumping results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the list of the `password policies` being used by the Realm, you should call the following endpoint:

```
GET <KEYCLOAK_HOST>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>
```

from the `JSON` response extract the field:

```
passwordPolicy
```

which for instance if you have set `Minimum length to 12` and `Hashing Iterations to 27500` the `passwordPolicy` would be `"length(12) and hashIterations(27500)"`